# I am attempting to pass a jpeg from an asset folder into a react component using .map and I am only getting the Urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to iterate over an array for my main page in a react project. The iteration is working but rather then rendering the images it is only returning the string. I am sure that it is something basic I am missing but not sure what to try next. this is the file i'm working with everything else is standard React...

```
import './App.css';
const App = () => {
  const faucets = [
    { id: 1, title: 'New Leaf Carbon Project', subtext: "Tasmanian Land Conservatory. Tasmania, Australia", imageUrl: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/TLC-Five-Rivers-Reserve-Credit-Matthew-Newton_02-862x689.jpeg', logo: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/CERLogo.png' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Afognak Island Forest Preservation', subtext: "South Pole. Alaska, United States", imageUrl: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/Afognak-Island-Forest-Preservation-Credit-Matthew-Newton_02-862x689.jpeg', logo: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/South Pole Logo.png' },
    { id: 3, title: 'Crow Lake Wind Farm', subtext: "South Pole. South Dakota, United States", imageUrl: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/Crow-Lake-Wind-Farm-Credit-Matthew-Newton_02-862x689.jpeg', logo: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/South Pole Logo.png' },
    { id: 4, title: 'Bac Lieu Wind Farm', subtext: "South Pole. Vietnam", imageUrl: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/Bac-Lieu-Wind-Farm-Credit-Matthew-Newton_02-862x689.jpeg', logo: './assets/Carbon Faucet/Projects/South Pole Logo.png' },
  ]
  return (
    <div>
      {faucets.map(({title, subtext, imageUrl, logo}) => (
      <div className="Project-Faucets">
        <div className="Project-Banner">
          {imageUrl}
        <div className="Project-Logo">
          {logo}
      </div>
      <div className="Project-Title">{title}</div>
      <div className="Project-Subtext">{subtext}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="Project-Content">
    </div>
  </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: How would you like to render and image without the `ing` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `{imageUrl}` with `<img src={imageURL} />`

The first one will only paste the text, the second is the correct syntax to load an image.

Same with `{logo}`